# What is the equation of the graph?

Tags: coordinate-systems

My Maths Mentor at first explained us the graph of the equation $y=[x]$ which looks like the following

[image]

then with a smile on the corner of this mouth he told

"It seems that you have understood the aforesaid graph.Then tell me what will be the equation of the following graph be?"

[image]

He gave us two weeks timing.I could not resist so I asked this question here
I dont if this graphs are even related?

Comment: looks like the graph of the relation $\{\,(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid \lfloor x\rfloor=y\lor x=\lfloor y\rfloor +1\,\}$

Comment: What is [x] meant to be in your equation? Is it $\lfloor{x}\rfloor$, which will give you the largest integer less than or equal to x?

Comment: yes i meant that

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

You can treat the graph as a parametrized curve.
choose a parameter $t $ and define
$(x(t),y(t)) $ for $t\in [n,n+1] $ and
$n\in\{-1,0,1,2,3\} $.

Answer (score 0):

A hint: what you are looking for is the graph of the following equation,
rotated $45$ degrees and dilated by a suitable constant factor:

$$y = \left|x - \lfloor x\rfloor - \frac12\right| - \frac12.$$

See [what Wolfram Alpha shows for this equation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3Dabs[x-floor[x]-1%2F2]-1%2F2).